# Git Rollback with previous comments

Tags: git, comments, rename, commit, history

I have a question related to git.
My problem is that I've changed the root folder name from the REPO and now I lost previous comments that I did on the repo. The command to rename it was.

```
git mv <old name> <new name>
```

However the problem is that I've inserted the Summary and Description using Git for windows, and then commit and Sync,

Once I've done the Sync, I lost all the comments before, since the commit  applies over all children folder/files the new description and summary.

There is way that will allow me to restore previous descriptions and summary that I was doing correctly until here?

Please git masters help me on this!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You did not loose the comments did you?
I guess what you mean is, that if you look at the history of those files, the latest commit and thus comment is from this moving right?
Well, if you want your root folder renamed there is no other way.
Git does not track directories, it just tracks the content of files.
So if you want to rename a directory you have to move all the things that are in this directory to the new directory which is what happened for you and is just fine.
If you really want to kill this commit, you can easily throw it out.
But be aware that it can result in major headaches if you pushed the changes and someone fetched it and worked on base of that, as you would rewrite published history.

Comment: HI Bjorn. Thank you for the reply. There is no problem with that in my case , since is my repository only. I am not expert in git to do stuff like this. Even if I rollback my last commit, which I did, the comments are still the new ones. And that's really what I am trying to recover.

Comment: Define "rollback", this is not a Git term, so I don't know what exactly you mean. If you did a `git revert` you just make the inverse of the commit you did as new commit. What you need is either `git reset` if it is the last commit you want to remove or `git rebase` if it is an older commit you want to remove. http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html is very helpful for fixing stuff in a Git repo.